# IRLZ44N MOSFET switch - voltage drop across brushless fan

Tags: mosfet, logic-level

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkVpIE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have an IRLZ44N with the gate connected to a 3.3v logic output pin as shown in the diagram below. The brushless fan is rated at 5v 200mA, so the resistance should be 25 Ohms. The fan is not switching on, and when I measure the voltage across the fan (labelled load in the diagram), it reads 1.5V. Removing the fan brings the voltage back up to 5v.

What is strange for me is that I'm seeing a similar behaviour when trying to switch using a BC517 NPN transistor as well.

I'm not sure what is causing the voltage drop here - is this normal and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Since you have a 5V rail, test if the fan turns on when you apply 5V to the gate. If that works just level-shift your 3.3V signal to 5V.

Comment: You can't really apply the logic of the resistance to the fan. Fans aren't resistors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gate threshold voltage is NOT the voltage you care about when using the MOSFET as a switch. That is the voltage where the MOSFET *just barely* starts to turn on.

You want the Vgs required for the rated RDson.

With 3.3V Vgs, you are right in the middle between the gate threshold voltage and the gate threshold voltage given for the highest rated RDson, so it could go either way whether the actual RDSon is a bit higher than rated (works) or a lot higher (doesn't work).

You can figure out what the RDson should be in the conditions you are running at using the Id vs Vds graph to find out what the RDson is at that condition.

Comment: You (the OP) can test if this is the problem. First verify if the gate is really 3.3V. Then, assuming it is, temporarily disconnect the 3.3V from the gate, and use a resistor to pull the gate up to 5V directly. Verify gate voltage with a volt meter.

Comment: @mkeith It is a little weird OP says he sees the same behaviour with a BJT but we don't have that circuit.

Comment: Hi. The BJT circuit is similar to http://www.fiz-ix.com/2012/11/how-to-use-an-npn-transistor-as-a-switch/ but with R1 = 220 Ohms, no R2, and the LED is replaced with the fan. The circuit worked when connecting the MOSFET gate directly to 5v instead of 3.3v, so it must have been not enough to switch on the MOSFET like what both of you have said. I haven't tested out the BJT yet and am not sure why that isn't working. I'm trying to figure out how to read the Id vs Vds graph like what DKNguyen has suggested.

Comment: @zhao Test the BJT circuit with a real 25 Ohm resistor. If it works, it is because the motor start up current is too high and saturating the BJT (which is different than MOSFET saturation because the same word is used for two different modes of operation which is dumb dumb dumb)

Comment: @DKNguyen Sorry - what do you mean by a real 200 Ohm resistor? I had checked the R1 (220 Ohm) resistor I used earlier and it read 225 Ohms I think....?

Comment: @Zhao Typo. 25Ohm resistor instead of fan. You can do same test with MOSFET. It is possible 3.3V gate-source is enough for 200mA but the start-up current of a real motor is too much and the MOSFET enters triode region (equivalent of saturation in a bjt)

Comment: @DKNguyen Don't have a 25Ohm resistor. Measured the following. 22 Ohm = 0.03V, 47Ohm = 0.06V, 220Ohm = 0.27V, 2200Ohm = 2.4V,  4700 = 4.7V, 6800Ohm = 5v. The brushless fan = 1.5V. I have a nice curve now with a polynomial fit but have no idea what this means physically.

Comment: 22 Ohm is close enough. So no workie at 22Ohms?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124564/discussion-between-zhao-and-dknguyen).

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility that the mosfet is not fully turning on. I notice that in the datasheet, R<sub>DS(on)</sub> is only listed for V<sub>GS</sub> of 4V and higher. Still, you are only switching a 200mA load. So it seems like probably the transistor should turn on enough for that load.

There could be some resistance in the wiring setup that is causing a voltage drop. It would be a good idea to stick the negative probe of your volt meter as close as you can to the power supply, then, with the positive probe, record voltage at the source of the transistor, the drain, the gate, the motor negative terminal, and the motor positive terminal, and the power supply itself, just to see if there are any unexpected voltage drops due to wires or traces acting like resistors.

Adding a photograph of your setup would also be helpful.

Other debugging ideas:
Remove the transistor and replace it with a wire from drain to source (keep all other wiring intact). Does the fan spin now? If not, the transistor has no chance.

With the transistor in place, disconnect the 3.3V from the transistor gate. Temporarily connect 5V to the gate. Does the fan spin now? If so, it suggests that 3.3V is not enough to fully turn on the transistor.